# Using Comparator instead compare method

Tags: java, comparator

I have this situation:

```
Stock.stream
.max(this::my_method)
.map....

public int my_method(Stock stock1, Stock  stock2) {
    int total1 = get_sum(stock1);
    int total2 = get_sum(stock2);

    if (total1 == total2) {
        return stock1.get_quantity() - stock2.get_quantity();
    }
    return total1 - total2;
}

 public Integer get_sum(Stock stock) {
    return stock.get_quantity() - stock.get_wasted();
}
```

Is there a way to write it using Java Comparator or it is for some other sithuations?

Comment: this sounds like a homework task, is it?

Comment: Well, just create a comparator and put the content of `my_method()` into its `compare()` method (you might have to make `get_sum()` available to the comparator though, but since it doesn't use anything except the parameter it could be a static method or function of its own). Then use that comparator in `max(...)` e.g. `max(MyComparator::new)`.

Comment: The question is not very clear. You have a method that can serve as an implementation of the Comparator functional interface. What do you want to change in it?

Comment: ...unless the point of the method is actually to compute that difference, in which case it should probably be left as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Comparator` with lambda. E.g. if you have the following class:

```
class Stock {
   int price;
}
```

You can use `max` with a comparator that uses `price`, e.g.:

```
List<Stock> stocks; //list
Stock max = stocks.stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparing((a) -> a.price))
    .get();
```